# Filter attachments *after* applying the default malware filter in Exchange online

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I want the following:

- If the a message contains known malware, delete it. (= Protection from known vulnerabilities)
- If a message does not contain know malware but contains a "potentially dangerous attachment", keep the message but replace the attachment with a message. (= Protection from zero-day vulnerabilities)

Office 365 offers [Common Attachment Blocking](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/06/office-365-have-you-enabled-common-attachment-blocking/), which does something similar, but not exactly the same:

- If a message contains a "potentially dangerous attachment", treat it like malware. If malware is found:

  1. Keep the message but replace the attachment with a message (or inform an administrator) or
  2. delete it.

Obviously, none of these two options is even remotely usable: The first option does not silently delete known malware, thus bothering users and/or administrators with messages that could safely be deleted, and the second option could cause benign e-mails to be lost.

Is it possible to configure a "sane" policy (as described at the top of my question) in Exchange Online?

Comment: I honestly don't understand the dilemma here. What you want 1) If the a message contains known malware, delete it. (= Protection from known vulnerabilities) and 2) If a message does not contain know malware but contains a "potentially dangerous attachment", keep the message but replace the attachment with a message. (= Protection from zero-day vulnerabilities) is already implemented. Note that EOP offers Anti-malware protection that is different from Common Attachment Blocking: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200731(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: @NoorKhaldi: Have a look at the screenshots in the link in my question: You need to change the *general* malware detection response to be able to only delete attachments in the case of non-recognized-malware, but potentially dangerous attachments.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see the problem, perhaps reading through this will help? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200664(v=exchg.150).aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj723164(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: @NoorKhaldi: Sorry, doesn't help. What exactly is unclear about my question? I'd love to improve it.